# insert line into a new file in linux using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I need to write shell script to create a new file and insert some stuffs into it. The problem is, using sed 'i/blablabla' command, it only works when there is at least one line existed in the file. What is the command to insert into a new file?

Thanks

Comment: do you actually need to edit the stream (do some find/replacement in the text) before you write it to the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo 'new line' >file_name
```

Also, you can append to the end without using sed using the `>>` operator:

```
echo 'additional line' >>file_name
```

Comment: Really appreciated. So sed could not be applied in this case?

Comment: sed could be used, but there's no need for it -- sed is for editing streams; editing implies starting with something and changing it; you're not doing that, so just using functionality built into the shell instead of starting a separate tool (such as sed) makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

More variants:

```
cat >>file_being_appended_to <<some_random_string
This is the first line
This is the second line and it has a variable in it; it's right here: $some_variable
some_random_string
```

```
cat >>file_being_appended_to <<'some_random_string'
This is the first line
This is the second line and it has a variable reference in it; it's right here: $some_variable,
but this variable reference is not expanded because the beginning delimiter string has single quotes around it.
some_random_string
```

Comment: Use `vi`? :) Seriously, I think you meant "If i want to _write a script to_ add a line to middle of file, what shoud i do???"?


    `(line_number=40; sed "$line_number,\$d" your_file; ((line_number--)); echo "stuff you want inserted";sed "1,${line_number}d" your_file) >your_new_file`

The first `sed` prints out the first part of the file; the second `sed` prints out the second part of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Other variants:

```
echo 'This is the first line
This is the second line.' >file
```

```
some_variable="some value"
echo "This is the first line
This is the second line and it has a variable in it; it's right here: $some_variable" >file
```